# Not able to load Css file for my express and socket chat app

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, socket.io

Hi guys I need some help here from the last two days I'm getting this problem that I'm not able to load my css for my express app

So, can someone help me with the solution

I would be grateful if anyone could help me

Below is my server.js code

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server);

const port = 80;

const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'css')));

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('new-user', name => {

        socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected',name);

    })

    socket.on('send name', (username) => {

        io.emit('send name', (username));

        console.log(username)

    });

    socket.on('send message', (chat) => {

        io.emit('send message', (chat));

        console.log(chat);

    });

    socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {

        socket.emit('chat-message',{ message: message, name: users[socket.id]})

        console.log(message);

    })

    socket.on('disconnect',(name) => {

        socket.emit('user-disconnected',name);

        console.log(name)

    })

});

server.listen(port, () => {

    //console.log(`Server is listening at the https://localhost:${port}/`);

    console.log(`Server is listening at the https://localhost/`);

});
```

I tried using this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'css')));
```

But still can't able to fix it

Am I Wrong somewhere?

Comment: How did you included the css in your html? Do you have a css folder ? Please add the html template file with the question itself

Comment: Yes I have a css folder but still it's not able to load it

Comment: Also I'm not been able to use my script.js also which is present in my js folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your CSS to your HTML file?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Yeah I got the fix btw thanks for helping me out brother :)